# Can't kill Alain Dufont with Dwemer Ballista in Dark Brotherhood 'Mourning Never Comes' quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm on the Dark Brotherhood '[Mourning Never Comes'](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mourning_Never_Comes) quest, to kill Alain Dufont.

I'm standing atop of the ledge looking down on him. [According to TES wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Alain_Dufont#Strategy), you are supposed to be able to fire the [Dwemer Ballista](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dwemer_Ballista#Dwemer_Ballista) in order to kill him, but that doesn't work. When I fire off the explosive arrows, they hit the ground at his feet but nothing happens. Alain and his bandits don't even react to being hit and they take no damage.

Has anyone encountered this bug?

Comment: Best reccomendation would be attempting to reload the save, if you haven't already done that several times. If that hasn't worked maybe try to go from a save before you even entered the ruin he's in, or before you've started Mourning Never Comes.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me. I solved it by firing an arrow a bit closer to the ballista so that they would walk towards it and better in the line of fire.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The problem is, as I said in my post, that they already are in the line of fire. It just that the game doesn't register the ballista impact as a hit.

Comment: Oh sorry when you said at his feet i thought it wasn't a direct hit. Have you tried hitting him with a low level arrow, then hiding till they resume and trying then?

Answer (score -3):

The best fix would be to kill him manually but if you don't think this is possible then try to reload a save.